# TYPO3 Invalidate cHash Cache / Index

Tags: typo3

I have successfully made my one-page extension output cached and indexed.
My extension allows for entities to be created and changed in the FE.

But when I change something I would like to invalidate the cache and index for the specific request parameters used.

I could not find anything on that topic, any ideas? Just deleting entries from the related mysql tables seems harsh ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the [caching framework](http://wiki.typo3.org/Caching_framework#How_to_use_the_caching_framework_in_extensions).

Answer (score 0):

The Caching Framework looks like a lot of work to implement.
So my dirty solution is to just delete the index entries from the mysql database:

```
SELECT phash FROM index_phash WHERE CONVERT(cHashParams USING utf8) LIKE '...'
DELETE FROM index_phash WHERE phash = ...
DELETE FROM index_fulltext WHERE phash = ...
DELETE FROM index_grlist WHERE phash = ...
DELETE FROM index_rel WHERE phash = ...
DELETE FROM index_section WHERE phash = ...
```

Comment: The index_* tables are related to indexed_search. It is not about caching.

Comment: I thought to remote the old search results I needed to delete the cache. Now i guess the old pages are still in the cache technically, but I worked around that and the cache will be cleared at midnight.

Comment: sorry, i did not read your post properly. I overlooked the "and index":) You can configure some stuff with the "crawler" extension. So indexed_search would update its index on daily base.